# Convert date/time field to a decimal in XML

Tags: xml, datetime, typeconverter, itrs

I was wondering if it was possible to extract the time from a date/time field for example Dec 1 2016 5.13am and convert the time to a decimal? 
I need to be able to subtract 2 date/time fields to get a duration but obviously I cannot do this with this format. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you put what you try?

Comment: Are you referring to the [dateTime datatype](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime) in XML Schema?

Comment: I am writing a rule on ITRS which grabs 2 dates from 2 cells and subtracts them to find out the duration of a process, the cells contain data from a database which is in datetime format, however the rule has to be written in xml.

Comment: I tried to convert them using the format function within the itrs gateway rule editor however it didn't work. The rule I have created will work with simple numbers but just returns 0 when I try it with the dates